# How to assign different colors avatar icon from pre defined color list for different users in a group chat?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a chat system.
I've an array of messages of different users.
I want to set different colour for different users.
The colours are defined in another array.

Suppose I've 5 colours, 10 users & 20 messages.

Now, what is the best way to set different colour for different users message in php?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

[image]

The image is collected from internet.
I'm trying to set different colors avatar instead of images for users in a group chat.

Comment: If you only have 5 colours and 10 users, you are going need some more colors...

Comment: You just need an array mapping user to colour and you're sorted

Comment: what's the meaning of the colors? If the colors doesn't have meaning use rand() to get your random colors for the users

Comment: Actually, I've an array of 80 fixed colors & have a lot of users. In a chat room there are so many users. So I Want to assign the color repeatedly for the users.

Comment: You can use `array_rand($colorArray)` to get random color for user

Comment: In that case, same user will get different color for different message. Actually I'm trying to differentiate the users by his color. 
But if user goes more than 80, then the color will assign from 1 repeatedly.

Comment: You can create array of user is key and color is random value from color array and when new user arrives it will have new entry into this array.

Comment: Thanks @DishaV.
I'm trying so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not assign the colors starting from 1 but uses each users name to select a color and keep it:

```
<?php
$color_array = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow');
$color_count = count($color_array);
$user_name = "Stephan B";
$color_index = crc32($user_name) % $color_count;
$user_color = $color_array[$color_index];
echo "Color for user '$user_name' is '$user_color'.";
// Color for user 'Stephan B' is 'orange'.
?>
```

This computes a checksum over the users name and truncates that to the number of colors in the array. If available you can use the IP or even email address to get the color, then they can change their name but not their color.

This is comparable to the [gravatar](http://de.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/) method.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Just a little bit change. It's give the array_key & have to set the color by that key.